# Iterating through XML tags using bash

Tags: xml, bash

I have an XML file that contains the following -

```
<File Name="something.txt" >
 <EmailWhenMissing>Customer</EmailWhenMissing>
 <CustomerEmail>somebody@email.com</CustomerEmail>
</File>
<File Name="somethingElse.txt" >
 <EmailWhenMissing>Customer</EmailWhenMissing>
 <CustomerEmail>somebodyelse@email.com</CustomerEmail>
</File>
```

Is there any way, or a best way to loop through each `<File>` element so that I can execute commands on them separately? (i.e. so that I would be able to identify which File tags have blank or missing elements)

Comment: I would recommend that you write a script in perl or python, using an XML module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand that your goal is to validate the fields present in each `File`, consider the following as a relevant example:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^- IMPORTANT: not /bin/sh

sep=$'\v' # pick a character that can't be in your data

while IFS="$sep" read -r Name EmailWhenMissing CustomerEmail; do
  # the line below this provides verbose logging when running with bash -x
  : Name="$Name" EmailWhenMissing="$EmailWhenMissing" CustomerEmail="$CustomerEmail"
  [[ $EmailWhenMissing ]] || { echo "File $Name is missing EmailWhenMissing"; }
  [[ $CustomerEmail ]] || { echo "File $Name is missing CustomerEmail"; }
done < <(xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//File' \
           -v ./@Name -o "$sep" \
           -v ./EmailWhenMissing -o "$sep" \
           -v ./CustomerEmail -n)
```

Given the following input file:

```
<root>
  <File Name="something.txt">
    <EmailWhenMissing>Customer</EmailWhenMissing>
    <CustomerEmail>somebody@email.com</CustomerEmail>
  </File>
  <File Name="somethingElse.txt">
    <EmailWhenMissing>Customer</EmailWhenMissing>
    <CustomerEmail>somebodyelse@email.com</CustomerEmail>
  </File>
  <File Name="NoEmailWhenMissing.txt">
    <CustomerEmail>somebodyelse@email.com</CustomerEmail>
  </File>
  <File Name="NoCustomerEmail.txt">
    <EmailWhenMissing>Customer</EmailWhenMissing>
  </File>
  <File Name="EmptyFile.txt"/>
</root>
```

...its output is:

```
File NoEmailWhenMissing.txt is missing EmailWhenMissing
File NoCustomerEmail.txt is missing CustomerEmail
File EmptyFile.txt is missing EmailWhenMissing
File EmptyFile.txt is missing CustomerEmail
```

---

With respect to the bash code here, some useful reading:

- [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) - *How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field?)*
- [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) - *I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?* - Explains the reasoning for the `< <(...)` loop form.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xmlstarlet`

```
for f in $(xmlstarlet select -t -v '//File/@Name' file.xml)
do
   echo $f
done
```

Comment: +1 for XMLStarlet, -1 for suggesting a `for` loop to iterate over line-oriented output. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: This didn't work for me.